# Explaining 烦百事生 in 雨下得人心烦百事生

Tags: translation

虹影  饥饿的女儿 Ying Hong - Daughter of the River  has the sentence 雨下得人心烦百事生，看不到雨停的希望。（google 烦百事生）。Howard Goldblatt＇s translation reads：The effect of the rain is despair that you'll ever see the end of it. How to explain 烦百事生.

Answer (score 3):

You can not find 烦百事生. "雨下得人心烦百事生，看不到雨停的希望。" should be read as 雨下得//人心烦//百事生，看不到雨停的希望。 It means that the rain make me so upset(人心烦), everything goes wrong(百事生), I don't know when the unpleasant rain stop.(看不到雨停的希望)

Comment: Also google `百事生` and you get a few more idioms.

Comment: Frankly,百事生 hard to find a word in English.A complicated mood which will have a negative influence to your life, may that means 人心烦//百事生.

Comment: in other words 百事生 is an S－P phrase （following the preceding S－P phrase 人心烦) with predicate 谓语 being the adjective 生 （raw，unripe，crude，uncooked，etc。）

Comment: @S.Rhee Your analysis on structure is correct, but 生 here is the verb means happen/emerge/grow. 百事生 literally means "hundreds of problems emerge".

Answer (score 2):

雨下得人心烦百事生 should be splitted as 雨/下得/人/心烦/百事生, which in plain language means that the rain is going on, making people feel annoyed and remember other annoying things.

下 means raining, 下得 starts a complement which states the effect brought by the long lasting rain. 心烦 means to feel bad. 百事生 literally means many things happen, but here it means to cause somebody to recall bad things.

By the way, in my opinion, 百事生 acts as a complement of 心烦. I'm not sure about it.